# rosmake fails on selfmade package

Tags: ros, roscreate-pkg, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason, rosmake fails whenever i try to make any packages that i created with roscreate-pkg with the same error:

```
desktop:~/ros/learning_actionlib$ rosmake learning_actionlib 
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                  
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['learning_actionlib']                       
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/xhab/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130319-140107
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['learning_actionlib'] to:
['learning_actionlib']      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> actionlib [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-4] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> actionlib_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                   
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< actionlib  No Makefile in package actionlib             
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib                   
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs               
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< actionlib_msgs  No Makefile in package actionlib_msgs   
[rosmake-5] Starting >>> learning_actionlib [ make ]                             
[ rosmake ] All 32 linesearning_actionlib: 9.7 sec ]    [ 1 Active 6/7 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  -- Action Files:Fibonacci.action
  -- Generating Messages for ActionFibonacci.action
  -- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/xhab/ros/learning_actionlib/build/devel
  -- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/xhab/ros/clam_catkin/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
  -- This workspace overlays: /home/xhab/ros/clam_catkin/devel;/opt/ros/groovy
  -- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
  -- catkin 0.5.63
  -- /home/xhab/ros/learning_actionlib/msg/FibonacciAction.msg
  [rosbuild] Building package learning_actionlib
  [rosbuild] Cached build flags older than manifests; calling rospack to get flags
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only learning_actionlib
  ImportError: No module named rospack
  terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rospack::Exception'
    what():  could not find python module 'catkin_pkg.rospack'. is catkin_pkg up-to-date (at least 0.1.8)?
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'learning_actionlib'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
    Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:227 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:14 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package learning_actionlib written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/xhab/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130319-140107/learning_actionlib/build_output.log
[rosmake-5] Finished <<< learning_actionlib [FAIL] [ 9.82 seconds ]              
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package learning_actionlib. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                             
[ rosmake ] Built 7 packages with 1 failures.                                    
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                          
[ rosmake ] /home/xhab/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130319-140107
```

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58603/rosmake-fails-on-selfmade-package/) by [smishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4473/smishra/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the error here is not with the learning_actionlib package, but with the core ros tool "rospack".  See this snippet from your log:

```
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack cflags-only-I;--deps-only learning_actionlib
ImportError: No module named rospack
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'rospack::Exception'
what():  could not find python module 'catkin_pkg.rospack'. is catkin_pkg up-to-date (at least 0.1.8)?
```

Check to see if rospack is available on your system: `which rospack`.  Then, check the version installed: `rospack --version`.  You could also check to see whether the debian package `ros-groovy-rospack` is installed on your system.

If all of those look correct, I have seen similar errors before when there is a conflict between older versions of the ros python tools installed using pip or easyinstall and the newer versions installed using debian packages.  See [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/49143/problems-with-rqt-groovy-ubuntu/?answer=49153#post-id-49153) for details on how to remove the older versions of the python tools.

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [smishra](https://answers.ros.org/users/4473/smishra/) on 2013-03-21**:
Thanks a lot, it was a problem with having an older version of th python tools, I followed the link you posted and now rosmake works fine.